# 'performFetch' fetches wrong object from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableVIew` that has a list of people. Now when I click on a particular cell, I `push` a new view controller that displays the detailed information related to that person. Now the issue is this mechanism works fine for all other `UITableVIew's` except for this one. When I click on a cell the information gets displayed but it's for a totally different cell. Say, if I click on the first cell the detailed information that is shown is for the last cell. This happens for all other cells, either the information is displayed wrong or it is blank. I am having a hard time trying to figure out why it works for all `UITableVIew's` and not just this one. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
NSEntityDescription *entity;

if ([activitytype isEqualToString:@"activitytask"])
{
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TaskActivity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"due_on" ascending:NO];
}
else if ([activitytype isEqualToString:@"activitychat"])
{
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ChatMessageActivity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_actdt" ascending:NO];
}
else if ([activitytype isEqualToString:@"activitycalendar"])
{
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CalendarActivity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_actdt" ascending:NO];
}

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = nil;
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = (id)self;
_fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Core Data Error. Could not save data to device.Please contact..."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSLog(@"%@", _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects);
return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you are using.

Comment: @NiravD - Plz check now, the fetch works fine for 'activitychat' and 'activitycalendar', but doesn't work for 'activitytask'.

Comment: You have said you have issue with TableView, then you need to show the tableView datasource methods.

Comment: @NiravD - My issue is the wrong data being fetched, I don't think it has anything to do with the datasource methods.

Comment: In your question you have said on cell click it is showing different data, "**if I click on the first cell the detailed information that is shown is for the last cell**" What does it mean?

Comment: @NiravD - Yes which mean the fetch is going wrong, doesn't it ?

Comment: If issue is with fetch tableView doesn't show any data, your issue is probably with dataSource method of TableView.

Comment: I doubt if you understood my question, my tableView displays data properly, the problem is when i click and and the details screen shows, the data is for different cell, idk why you think it has something to do with the datasource ?